# Is there a way to replace NAs in muliple columns in an R dataframe

Tags: r

I am using the below code to replace N/As in multiple columns (but not all columns) in an R dataframe , however I am devoting a line of code for each column. I wondered if there is a cleaner and tidyier way of doing this. See code below

```
csvDF$Carechildinneed[is.na(csvDF$Carechildprotectionplan)] <- ""
csvDF$Carechildprotectionplan[is.na(csvDF$Carechildprotectionplan)] <- ""
csvDF$Careeligiblechild[is.na(csvDF$Careeligiblechild)] <- ""
csvDF$Careorder[is.na(csvDF$Careorder)] <- ""
csvDF$Carerelevantchild[is.na(csvDF$Carerelevantchild)] <- ""
csvDF$Careremandtolaa[is.na(csvDF$Careremandtolaa)] <- ""
csvDF$Careremandtoyda[is.na(csvDF$Careremandtoyda)] <- ""
csvDF$Caresiblings[is.na(csvDF$Caresiblings)] <- ""
csvDF$Carevoluntary[is.na(csvDF$Carevoluntary)] <- ""
```

Comment: does your first line have a typo? (the variables to be replaced/checked for NAs don't match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace `NA` values in the `'Care'` columns in base R, you can do -

```
cols <- grep('Care', names(csvDF))
csvDF[cols][is.na(csvDF[cols])] <- ''
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `replace` to replace the `NA` elements to `''` after looping `across` the columns

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     mutate(across(cols, ~ replace(., is.na(.), "")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(across(cols, ~replace_na(.,"")))
```

If you save the columns you wish to modify in the vector `cols`.

As @Ben mentioned in the comments, you can use the tidyervse `tidyselect` functions such as `starts_with("Care")`, for example.

```
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Care", ~replace_na(.,"")))
```

The rest can be found [here](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html).